# How to overwrite linear-gradient function in Compass?

Tags: compass-sass, sass

I'd like to use the code [here](https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/965) to overwrite the `linear-gradient` function that comes with Compass. How can I do this?

I think what I need is a way to import the `linear-gradient` function and then locally rename it to something else, so that my own `linear-gradient` function can call it. E.g. something like:

```
@import "compass/css3/images";

// somehow make `original-lg` alias the current `linear-gradient`

@function linear-gradient($args...) {
  @return original-lg($args...) + ", " + fixed-lg-from-link-above($args...);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are attempting won't work, because we are dealing with prefixed values that have to be split apart into distinct properties. As the author of the linked code, here is how I recommend using it. You'll need these functions:

```
@function convert-gradient-angle(
  $deg
) {
  @if type-of($deg) == 'number' {
    @return mod(abs($deg - 450), 360deg);
  } @else {
    $direction: compact();
    @if nth($deg,1) == 'to' {
      @if length($deg) < 2 {
        $direction: top;
        @warn "no direction given for 'to'. Using 'to bottom' as default.";
      } @else { $direction: opposite-position(nth($deg,2)); }
      @if length($deg) > 2 { $direction: append($direction, opposite-position(nth($deg,3)), space);}
    } @else {
      $direction: append($direction, to, space);
      @each $pos in $deg { $direction: append($direction, opposite-position($pos), space); }
    }
    @return $direction;
  }
}

@function convert-gradient(
  $angle,
  $details...
) {
  @return linear-gradient(convert-gradient-angle($angle), $details...);
}
```

The problem is, if you use multiple-backgrounds or anything like that, you will have to repeat the functions yourself in different properties. If you just want a simple background-image gradient, you can use this to simplify:

```
@mixin gradient-background-image(
  $gradient...
) {
  @include background-image(convert-gradient($gradient...));
  background-image: linear-gradient($gradient...);
}
```

Otherwise you will need to write those two lines by hand, adding the other layers as needed.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping to get something similar to the built-in `linear-gradient` function, so that I could do `@include background-image(linear-gradient(...))`. Since the original function somehow gets converted into multiple properties, I was hoping this one would too.

Comment: Yeah, I'd like that too. It should be coming soon in the next Compass 0.13 pre-release, but it requires re-writing the Ruby function. It can't be done simply in Sass.

Comment: Ah, that "can't be done in SASS" was the real answer. Thanks very much.

Comment: you are not answering the original question. In my case I would like to override sass predefined color functions like lighten - i want to override them and at some point call the original one

Comment: @cancerbero Your question sounds interesting, and it does match the title here – but the details are very different. I'd recommend opening a new question. Let me know if you do, I'd be happy to help - but I'll need a few more details.